# Why ID of an element is changing after adding directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have number of divs getting created using `ng-repeat`. ID of those divs are assigned like this

```
id={{""+date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getFullYear()+"-"+time+":00"}}
```

So ID of a div becomes like this `id="10-0-2014-00:00"`

but when i add `droppable`(custome directive) in div, ID becomes this `id="---:30"`. what might be the issue? is there any solution to avoid this issue?

droppable directive-

```
app.directive('droppable', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      drop: '&',
      bin: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // again we need the native object
      var el = element[0];

      el.addEventListener(
        'dragover',
        function(e) {
          e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
          // allows us to drop
          if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        },
        false
      );

      el.addEventListener(
        'dragenter',
        function(e) {

          return false;
        },
        false
      );

      el.addEventListener(
        'dragleave',
        function(e) {

          return false;
        },
        false
      );

      el.addEventListener(
        'drop',
        function(e) {
          // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
          if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();


          var binId = this.id;
          console.log(this)
          var item = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
          console.log(item)
          //this.appendChild(item);
          // call the passed drop function
          scope.$apply(function(scope) {
            var fn = scope.drop();
            if ('undefined' !== typeof fn) {            
              fn(item.id, binId);
            }
          });

          return false;
        },
        false
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you intentionally want to create your own (isolated) scope for this directive? If not, I would suggest you drop the scope property of your directive. `date` probably doesn't exist in your isolated scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `scope:{}` property in your directive. It will create an entirely new scope that will not inherit from the parent scope. This is why date doesn't show up at all in in your new scope:

> An isolate scope does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope, but creates an entirely new one. Creating this isolate scope will ensure that your directive does not mess with the existing scope.

Simply remove the scope object and it should work as expected.

Source: [Building custom directives](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html)

Comment: is it possible to define date in scope object? or is there other way to do it without removing scope? your method is working i mean the IDs are getting created as expected after removing scope. but it is giving me lot of errors

Comment: is there any way to define/add date in that scope

Comment: I just asked you to post the errors. Despite your persistence: you *may* be able to do `$scope.date = $parent.date;` or something of the like.

Answer (score 0):

just call return function. You dont require the scope for directive. It will create new scope each time when you assign droppable directive.